# How to run continuous workers in python - Real time data transfer?

Tags: python, flask

I have 2 different python applications which fit into the `producer-consumer` model.

1. A producer, written in `flask` framework
2. A consumer, `openerp v-8.0 (odoo)`

I want the producer to keep pushing data into a queue. The consumer then keeps pulling the data from the queue and operates accordingly.

To give further details - The producer keeps checking if there is a new order in the orders table and pushes all the required data to the queue so that the corresponding order is created in the consumer.

I want to be able to scale this model for 1000 orders per minute.

I am planning to use Amazon's SQS for queue due to its reliability and long polling feature(I don't know how to implement long polling but willing to learn).

So, my question is:

1. How do I add a worker that keeps on running in my flask app and pushes data as soon as an order is created?
2. How to run a continuous worker in openerp that keeps on pulling from the queue?
3. Is there a better way of doing this than what I have suggested?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

I think that you can use another architecture to make this happen.

Since you have a orders table, even i dont know what tech this table use, you can use any CDC or streams pattern.

You are looking to use SQS, then i'll assume that you are running in AWS.

With AWS dynamodb, you can make a dynamodb streams to tell another applications that data in your tables have changed:
https://aws.amazon.com/pt/blogs/database/dynamodb-streams-use-cases-and-design-patterns/

With this, you don't need to keep your flask application producing data into an SQS queue, you simply need to use dynamodb streams and have a lambda function or a application running in EC2 using KCL (Kinesis client library) to consume streams and do anything you want.

If you are using different database technology, you can use CDC, that is a technology to read actions logs of databases and send this message to an event listener, for example Kafka.